# How to extract +93 form Country name with code

Tags: java, android

I want to extract country code(+93)
 ex: `Afghanistan(+93)` here i need only `+93` how to remove Country name and braces

```
          final Bundle GetData = getIntent().getExtras();
    String rl = GetData.getString("countrycode");
    for (String country : rl) {

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(country, "()");
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        String codeVal = tokenizer.nextToken();
        CountryCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SpCountryCode);
        CountryCode.setText(codeVal);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use something like this;

```
  String s = "Afghanistan(+93)";
  int plusf = s.indexOf("(");
  int plusl = s.indexOf(")");
  String newString = s.substring(plusf+1, plusl);
  System.out.println(newString);
```

Output is : +93

For your list try this;

```
        String[] rl = { "Afghanistan(+ff93)", "Afghanistan(+93)", "Afghanistan(+493)", "Afghanistan(+454593)" };

        for (String country : rl) {

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(country , "()");
            tokenizer.nextToken();
            String codeVal = tokenizer.nextToken();
            System.out.println(codeVal);

        }
```

Comment: There are countries with more than 2 digits for eg. CZE got +420

Comment: If i take array of country code..? now it is string s = " "

Comment: @NickT He mean something, And if you take array of countries simply loop through them.

Comment: I am finding the ( and ) indexes and then taking string between them. So it is not important 420 or 93 or 45698855. I also editted sthg to something, sorry.

Comment: just now i am updated my source code above. I am bit confusing your code my it is not working. Can u update

Comment: ıf you send your whole code, I can help you, there are lots of absent objects at this part like addresses, CountryZipCode, R etc. @raghavan, did you tried my answer?

Comment: R.array.Country_Code it contains all country codes like Afghanistan(+93). I am not getting how to loop this. Sorry

Comment: Did you try list version?

Answer (score 0):

'StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(stringCode, "()");
tokenizer.nextToken();
String codeVal = tokenizer.nextToken();
'